# Can I connect my MacBook Pro DisplayPort to a Thunderbolt iMac to use as a display?

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, display, thunderbolt, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro with Mini DisplayPort and I want to use target display mode to use a Thunderbolt iMac as an external display. If this works, would I need a Mini DisplayPort cable or a Thunderbolt cable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://blog.macsales.com/10899-target-display-mode-and-thunderbolt) source, you won't be able to do that. You have to have a Thunderbolt Mac and use a Thunderbolt cable to use a Thunderbolt iMac as an external display. [This other source](http://mike952.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/thunderbold-and-minidisplay-mac-compatibility-101/) has a table that confirms it. Sorry!

Comment: Yep. Just to confirm, I've tried it and it doesn't work. Although the connectors are physically the same, the protocols are incompatible.